# How to set the FrontendUserGroup in AllowViewHelper of VHS in a partial?

Tags: typo3, partials, extbase, viewhelper

I'd like to set the **frontendUserGroup** parameter in the [AllowViewHelper](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/1.8.0/Security/AllowViewHelper.html) but I don't know how to do that.

Sometimes (non-deterministic even if I flush the caches) there pop up this error:

> The argument "frontendUserGroup" was registered with type
>   "TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FrontendUserGroup", but is of type
>   "string" in view helper
>   "FluidTYPO3\Vhs\ViewHelpers\Security\AllowViewHelper"

Is it right to pass simply the reference of the usergroup as argument as follows?:

```
{namespace v=FluidTYPO3\Vhs\ViewHelpers}
...
<v:security.allow frontendUserGroup="3">
  <f:then>
    <span>Access granted</span>
  </f:then>
  <f:else>
    <span>Access denied</span>
  </f:else>
</v:security.allow>
```

The parameter is registered by the ViewHelper as follows:

```
$this->registerArgument('frontendUserGroup', 'TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FrontendUserGroup', 'The FrontendUserGroup to allow/deny');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your example you might just use the security.hasRole ViewHelper shipped with CMS Fluid:

```
<f:security.ifHasRole role="3">
  <f:then>
    <span>Access granted</span>
  </f:then>
  <f:else>
    <span>Access denied</span>
  </f:else>
</f:security.ifHasRole>
```

In contrary to the allow ViewHelper from EXT:vhs, this ViewHelper accepts the UID of a user group as argument. Instead of the UID you can also pass the title of the usergroup, but as far as I know this can be ambiguous.

Answer (score 3):

You should pass the actual FrontendUserGroup Object (`TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FrontendUserGroup`) to your view. Extbase provides the repository, that you can inject into your controller:

```
/**
 * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Repository\FrontendUserGroupRepository
 * @inject
 */
protected $frontendUserGroupRepository;

public function myAction() {
        ....
        $this->view->assign('specialUserGroup', $this->frontendUserGroupRepository->findByUid(3));
}
```

Now pass this object to the viewHelper:

```
<v:security.allow frontendUserGroup="{specialUserGroup}">
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'dont really want to create an own controller for that, so I accept the anwser of @lorenz. But I give you an upvote :)